# importhtml different number of columns in each URL throws error & further need to move/shuffle columns

Tags: arrays, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import tables with different number of columns. This resulted in error "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more row" it seems the number of columns should be the same.

Further I need help regarding second URL table where in the output:

a) B column should be in the <strike>G</strike> "H" column

b) Shuffle the columns like in the second URL table output, C,D columns should be in the B,C columns. E,F columns should be F,E. )

the sheet is attached [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VdFMzRTwcaFAglGNpqvzGytdz_mqohtxGgAywKlLi0U/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your 2nd imported table outputs #N/A so you are actually putting 6 columns in array with one column/one cell

[image]

---

if you want to proceed anyway use:

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.financialexpress.com/market/stock-market/nse-top-gainers/", "table", 2),
 "where Col1 is not null", 1), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.financialexpress.com/market/stock-market/nse-buyers/",      "table", 2), 
 "where Col1 is not null offset 1", 0), {"","","","","",""})},
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.financialexpress.com/market/stock-market/nse-top-gainers/", "table", 2),
 "select Col1,' ',Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 
  where Col1 is not null 
  label ' ''Bid Qty'", 1), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.financialexpress.com/market/stock-market/nse-buyers/",      "table", 2), 
 "where Col1 is not null offset 1", 0), {"","","","","","",""})},
 "where Col1 is not null", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I've added another sheet now which is showing both the tables,  please check.

Comment: I checked.. its great... Thank you so much... is there anyway to swap E,F data in the second URL to F,E (In the first URL the order is change, change % but in the second table it is reversed change%, change, in the website itself)

Comment: use: `=QUERY({
 IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.financialexpress.com/market/stock-market/nse-top-gainers/", "table", 2),
 "select Col1,' ',Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 
  where Col1 is not null 
  label ' ''Bid Qty'", 1), {"","","","","",""});
 IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://www.financialexpress.com/market/stock-market/nse-buyers/",      "table", 2), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col6,Col5,Col7 
  where Col1 is not null offset 1", 0), {"","","","","","",""})},
 "where Col1 is not null", 1)`